# Why is the image in my svg pattern not tiling?

Tags: svg

Here's my test svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg version="1.1"
  viewBox="-1 -1 2 2" width="100" height="100"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" width="1" height="1">
            <image
                href="file:///tmp/test.png"
                patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <polygon points="0.0,0.0 1,-1, 1,1" fill="url(#img1)" />
</svg>
```

this is `test.png`, it is 2x2 pixels

[image]

The whole thing renders like this

[image]

I want the background `test.png` to tile infinitely in both directions, and I want to scale it.

My coordinate system for drawing is (0,0) at the centre to +/- 1 unit in the x and y directions. Ideally I can specify things relatively, e.g. if I scale the image to 5% then I expect it to repeat 20 times (1÷5%) across the whole image.

Initially I tried adding `width="50%" height="50%" and it renders like this

[image]

It seems to have shrunk as expected, but it doesn't seem to be repeating so most of it is disappearing to the left of the central (0,0) point. If I shrink the width and height percentages it progressively shrinks out of view to the top left, leaving the polygon empty.

Why isn't this tiling?

Comment: Your viewBox is 2 user units (px) wide. Also test.png is 2 px wide.

Answer (score 1):

I find patterns confusing in SVG, so I always try to explicitly add patternContentUnits as well as patternUnits, and also position and dimension each element within the pattern. When I do this, I can usually see how the silent defaults might be tripping me up, and fix it.

```html
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="-1-1 2 2" width="100px" height="100px">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" width="0.5" height="0.5" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
             <image x="0" y="0" width="0.5" height="0.5"
                xlink:href="https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20210507/ourmid/pngtree-world-graphics-day-four-color-circular-pattern-png-image_3249964.jpg"/>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <polygon points="0.0,0.0 1,-1, 1,1" fill="url(#img1)" />
</svg>
```